# Que veut dire sakaoulé ?

Tags: créole, antilles

Je croyais que cela voulait dire "ça qu'à rouler" en créole c'est à dire "c'est parti" ou "c'est bon comme ça".
Mais je ne trouve pas de référence, seulement qu'en calédonien c'est un synonyme de doudou/chérie et que ça veut dire antillais.

Comment: Terme péjoratif pour désigner un Antillais. Voir la [base de données lexicographiques panfrancophone](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=NC&no=518391&rubrique=). En créole *sa ka roulé* veut dire « ça va ». Synonyme de [doudou/madoudou](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=NC&no=518392&rubrique=) mais pas de « chérie ».

Comment: Je vais poser une vraie question, ca n'est pas du trolling ou de la ségrégation ou autre, mais est-ce que cette question a sa place ici ? Le créole est-il considéré comme une variation du français (comme on peut considérer qu'il y a un français de France, de Belgique, du Québec, voire d'Afrique) ?

Comment: Laurent S. > Étant donné qu'il n'y a pas de SE dédié aux créoles de la francosphère, je dirais que oui. Mais la remarque se comprend.